# What's the file format of "application/x-executable"

Tags: 18.04, file-format

No no no no. I can run the file. My favorite game is that file format and I can run it just fine. Same as other programs with it. My question is what the file format of it? You know. Things like `.sh`, or `.exe`, `.txt`, `.rar`, etc, etc. So, if you know just tell me.

So you know, the question isn’t about the game. It’s about the file format. The question has nothing to do about the game. And I already figured out about the file format. It’s `.86_64`. I didn’t notice the answer that was posted to this question so I had to figure it out myself. For anyone who is reading this now, I will close this question soon.

Comment: Insufficient data. Might be binary, might be something else. You must provide more information for the specific game you are asking about.

Comment: I’m not talking about the game, i’m just asking about the file format

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by "file format". `application/x-executable` is an inofficial MIME type identifier, not a single specific file type. You can use the `file` utility to try to detect file formats based on "magic numbers" at well known positions and you can use the result to research the structure of those file formats.

Comment: Question authors cannot close their own question and your question is already closed. You can only *delete* your own questions if they have no answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine the file format using the `file` utility e.g.

```
$ mimetype /bin/bash
/bin/bash: application/x-executable

$ file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=17150535c59ef39d9b6db94479a51fcd69942a0c, stripped
```

The extension .sh, .exe, .txt, .rar, etc. has no special significance in Linux.